Parameterising Surfaces Integration
$S$ is the surface of a cube which is bounded by $6$ planes being $x=1,x=3,y=2,y=4,z=0,z=2$. The normal vector points outwards and the vector field is $F = (x^2-sin(yz),\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}-yz,x^2y)$
First I must compute $\int \int_S F \cdot n dS$. I just applied Gauss' Divergence Theorem and got $8$. I believe this is correct.
After that I need to express the cube as a union of $6$ surfaces, parameterise one of them, compute the fundamental vector product there and express the integral on that specific surface as a double integral $\int \int_{S_1} F \cdot n dS$
So I choose the surface where $z=0$ and the four vertices are $(1,2,0),(1,4,0),(3,2,0),(3,4,0)$. The orientation of the vertices is obviously clockwise so the normal vector points downwards as this is the outward pointing normal vector right?
As the normal vector is outward pointing, it points downwards here and is $(0,0,-1)$. I believe this gives $\int \int_{S_1} (x^2-sin(yz),\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}-yz,x^2y) \cdot (0,0,-1) dy dx = \int_{1}^{3} \int_{2}^{4} -x^2y dy dx = -52 $
Is this correct? Am I also correct that if I did this for all $6$ surfaces and computed the sum, it should equal my original answer of $8$?

The integral $\int_{1}^{3} \int_{2}^{4} -x^2y dy dx=-52$ looks correct. What seems wrong is the volume integral of the divergence. I get $$
\int_1^3\int_2^4\int_0^2 \underbrace{2x-z}_{\operatorname{div}F}\ dz,dy,dx=24,.
$$

@KurtG. Are you sure? I got the exact same integral and it worked out as $8$

One is never sure but I refuse to go down to that level. Spoiler.

@KurtG. Sorry I was being stupid. What did the question mean when it said fundamental vector product?

Can I assume that you know Gauss' theorem? It does not matter how you call the vector product in the integral $\int \int_{S_1} F \cdot n dS,.$ Your $-52$ shows that you are on the right track. Now do the exercise for all six faces of the cube and compare the result with the volume integral.

@KurtG. Yes sir. I encountered one problem. For the face with vertices $(1,2,0),(1,2,2),(1,4,0),(1,4,2)$, the outward normal vector is $(-1,0,0)$. But the double integral is of $x^2-sin(yz)$ with respect to $y$ and $z$. Doesn't this mean that I will be left with $x$ terms in my integral?

No. What is $x$ on the face of the cube spanned by those four vertices?

@KurtG. I am guessing I should substitute in $x=1$ into the answer of that integral right?

Don't guess. Hint: the final match of volume integral being equal to the sum of six surface integrals will confirm this. Case closed.

@KurtG. Okay I will do all $6$ surfaces in a bit and come back to this. By the way when I tried for the face opposite to the one I mentioned in the question, I obtained $52$ which makes sense.

@KurtG. I tried and I get the opposite faces always being equal and opposite to each other. Can you please help me?

The vector field
$$
F= \pmatrix{x^2-\sin(yz)\\\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}-yz\\x^2y}
$$
has divergence $\operatorname{div}F=2x-z\,.$ Thus, the volume integral in Gauss' theorem is
$$
\int_1^3\int_2^4\int_0^2 2x-z\ dz\,dy\,dx=24\,.
$$
The six surface integrals come out as

\begin{align}&\int_2^4\int_0^2(-1^2+3^2)\,dz\,dy=8\cdot 2\cdot 2=32\,,\\&\int_1^3\int_2^4(x^2y-x^2y)\,dy\,dx=0\,,\\&\int_1^3\int_0^2(2z-4z)\,dz\,dx=-8\,.\end{align}

and sum up to $24$ as they should.

I understand everything now and can do the integrals without looking at your hint. Thanks for your help.
